# How can I test AsyncTask no called?

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, mockito

I'm writing some tests against an Activity. In the `onCreate()` method of my Activity I have an async call. I'd like to write a test to verify that the AsyncTask was not called. How can I do this? I've attempted to mock AsyncTask, but I can't because `execute()` being a final method.

My initial thought were to do something like this:

```
 val mockedTask = mock(QuoteOfTheDayTask::class.java)
 verify(mockedTask, never()).execute()
```

But now, having run into a few issues trying to test this way, I'm beginning to think that maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. It almost feels like I shouldn't be trying to test this against the activity, but right now that's where the call is made.